# Repeating elements of list with copying

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, repeat

I need to repeat every element of a list N times, i.e. perform this kind of transformation:

```
(1 2 3) => (1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3) ; N = 3
```

It is important to preserve the order of elements, i.e. first element should be repeated N times, then second, etc.

This is my best attempt so far:

```
(defun my-fnc (lst &optional (n 2))
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (make-list n :initial-element x))
          lst))
```

Looks like it works:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo* '("foo" "bar"))
*FOO*
CL-USER> (setf *foo* (my-fnc *foo* 3))
("foo" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar")
```

...but not quite. The problem is that former three elements are references to the same object.

```
("foo" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar")
;{---------------} {---------------}
; the same string   the same string
```

This is not what I want.

So my question is: how to solve the problem in most idiomatic way, so that every element of result list would be reference to copied separate object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible to do in general because Common Lisp does not provide a generic copy function. Moreover,

- some objects are immediate (e.g., [`fixnum`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fixnum.htm)) and cannot be copied in any meaningful sense
- some objects are [immutable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_i.htm#immutable) and copying them is a waste
- some objects are nested and you will have to decide whether you want [deep or shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

However, if you have resolved the problem and provided the copy function, it is not too hard:

```
(defun my-fnc (list &key (repeat 2) copy-function)
  (mapcan (if copy-function
              (lambda (x) 
                (loop :repeat repeat :collect (funcall copy-function x)))
              (lambda (x) (make-list n :initial-element x)))
          list))
```

Note that *all* the element of the `list` argument are copied, i.e., the return value has no [intersection](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_isec_.htm) with the argument (under the [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) test and assuming that the `copy-function` returns a [fresh](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#fresh) object)

Comment: With which function do I copy an adjustable string with fill-pointer, so that result would be also adjustable string? I just tried your method with `copy-seq`, but it produces arrays with fixed-size...

Comment: @Mark: I don't think there is function which does just that, but you can whip one up yourself using `make-array` - or just ask a separate question.

Comment: OK, thanks, now I know how to finish my algorithm. It's gonna be a bit bulky, but now I know that there is nothing better.